# Navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I'm  trying to do basic navigation in flutter (yes, I'm a noob), but it doesn't seem to be working. I have three files in my lib folder;

```
main.dart
home.dart
about.dart
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './home.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple), home: homePage());
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './about.dart';

class homePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Navigation',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Flutter Navigation'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Click Here'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  elevation: 0,
                  minimumSize: Size(200, 50),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  )
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => about(),
                )),
),
]
),
)
  )
);
}
}
```

Excuse how ugly the end of that looks.

Please let me know if you want to see the contents of `about.dart` but it's fairly irrelevant as that `navigator.push` from 'home' to 'about' doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you share what error log detail you get in the console.

Comment: The method 'about' isn't defined for the class 'homePage'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'about'.

Comment: Restarting android studio didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Use only **context** instead of **BuildContext**

Error in your code :

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => about(),
                )),
```

My solution :`

```
  onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => about(),
            )),
```

Comment: But that was for type

Comment: make sure your 'onPressed:' is working by printing something on your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it going, so I want to post the answer in case anyone else has trouble with this (we all know how much criticism there's been of Flutters navigation system).

I hadn't set up my routes, and I needed a class in my second page `about.dart` Which I seem to have above, but somehow got lost in my real code. Anyway, the code should look something like the below;

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './about.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Landing(),
    //new
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/about': (BuildContext context) => new about()
    },
  ));
}

class Landing extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new LandingBody(),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Welcome'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LandingBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LandingBodyState createState() {
    return new LandingBodyState();
  }
}

class LandingBodyState extends State<LandingBody> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            //Content goes in here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}// I haven't double checked all the opening/closing
```

about.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class about extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // styling for appbar goes here
            title: Text('Welcome'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // content goes here
              ]
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

This may not be a perfect representation. Some of the opening/closing may not be completely correct, but a copy/paste of this should be enough to get the system working in a fairly short time.